# Xamarin Activity OnCreate ActionBar is null

Tags: c#, android, nullpointerexception, android-actionbar, xamarin

I just upgraded Xamarin to their next "stable" version. I seem to be having issues with my class that inherits Activity. The ActionBar seems to be null for some reason when it wasn't before. I'm quite puzzled as to why this is happening now.

```
public class NavigationDrawerActivity : Activity
{
    //...

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);

        //...
        // NullPointerException, this.ActionBar is null.
        this.ActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled (true);
        this.ActionBar.SetHomeButtonEnabled (true);

        //...       
    }
    //...
}
```

This code is based off of this: http://developer.xamarin.com/samples/NavigationDrawer/

Does anyone have any ideas as to what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I figured it out. Apparently I need to inherit ActionBarActivity instead of Activity. I had to add the component `Android Support Library v7 AppCompat` and add `using Android.Support.V7.App;`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by change default app theme, in your AndroidManifest.xml

from :

> android:theme="@android:style/AppTheme"

to:

> android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"